# How to view an RTSP stream using HTML5 or JavaScript, without using plugins like VLC plugin on Real Player plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, web, streaming, rtsp

The idea is to develop a cross-platform, standalone application that could play a video, streamed over RTSP, using HTML5 or JavaScript or any other web technology.

Comment: answers to that question do no discuss about solutions using JavaScript in detail. I understand that I can not use the HTML5 video tag, but I want to know whether this can be done using JS or any other web technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTSP is a protocol on the same level as HTTP. Its impossible to do RTSP via HTTP.

The HTML5 video tag could support RTSP but no browser implements it.

It may be possible to create an RTSP proxy using websockets but that wouldn't be true rtsp any more. And it would mean, all the demuxing and protocol stuff had to be implemented in JS which would be quite inefficient.

I think your best alternative would be using either HTTP streaming with the video tag or WebRTC.

Comment: Impossible? AFAIK RTSP can be tunneled over HTTP and the RTSP is embedded within the HTTP body as base64 encoded data...

Comment: "RTSP over HTTP" wouldn't be "RTSP" but "RTSP over HTTP". Like I said, you can also tunnel it over Websockets which would be more effective then HTTP, but either way, it would still be quite inefficient.