# RTSP not working in all Browsers

Tags: jquery, html, video-streaming, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am using bellow code for playing video from my Chanel provider ....but it is working only for IE8 and + browser not working in Mozilla and other advance browser 
so I want code which can work over other browser as well IE8+ please help me

I google it but not able to find video streaming having rtsp provider

```
  <OBJECT 
  classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95' 
  codebase='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701' type='application/x-oleobject' width="513" height="411"
  standby='Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...' class="movie_table" id='mediaPlayer'>
  <param name='fileName' value="rtsp://live.soundviewtv.org:8080">
  <param name='animationatStart' value='true'>
  <param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
  <param name='autoStart' value="true">
  <param name='showControls' value="true">
  <param name='loop' value="false">
  <EMBED type='application/x-mplayer2'
    pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
    id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1' 
    bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1' 
    showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="513" height="411"
    src="mms://s/SoundView_Live/soundview_live.html" autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="false">
  </EMBED>
  </OBJECT>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view an RTSP stream using HTML5 or JavaScript, without using plugins like VLC plugin on Real Player plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831917/how-to-view-an-rtsp-stream-using-html5-or-javascript-without-using-plugins-like)